# Running aiohttp application as a coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an asyncio app and I want to add a simple REST API to it using aiohttp. As far as I can see, I can either create an aiohttp app and run it with `aiohttp.web.run_app` on another thread, or I'd have to forget about the app and use the lower level `aiohttp.web.Server` API. Is there a way I can use `aiohttp.web.Application` and then run the web application as a coroutine instead of using `run_app`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open sourced code for `aiohttp.web:run_app` (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web.py#L413-L467) and see how it's implemented.

You could do the same but don't call blocking `loop.run_forever()`.

Comment: That's what I'm looking at right now. I'm hoping to be able to send a PR upstream. I've refactored `run_app` so that most of its functionality resides in a new coroutine called `launch_app`. Unfortunately although this seems to be working fine, most `run_app` tests fail so far. I'll try working on it a little more to see if I can fix the issues. If not, I'll just try doing this in my own code, but copying code from aiohttp sounds a bit hacky. I was hoping for a better solution, but apparently there isn't one.

Comment: Huh. Didn't manage to find that even though I googled for the topic using several search terms. Thanks for pointing that out.